# Foreign key relationships in entity design

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have these two entities. One for Employees:

```
[Table(Name = "Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a first name")]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [DisplayName("Department")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
}
```

And one for Departments:

```
[Table(Name = "Departments")]
public class Department
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a department name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my database, I have a foreign key relationship between these two tables on DepartmentID. But in my entity classes, I have nothing that specifies this.

Do I need to add something to these classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you hand-generating the entity classes?  (why are you not using sqlmetal.exe and/or .dbml files?)  Hand-writing the classes is not the way to go, as LinqToSql provides truly awful exception messages when the error is in how the entities are defined.

But to answer your question, yes, you are missing the `[Association]` attributes. (which sqlmetal.exe would have generated for you.)  Without this, you cannot as easily write LINQ queries that operate across tables/relationships.

Something like:

```
[Column]
[DisplayName("Department")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a department")]
public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

private EntityRef<Department> department;

[Association(IsForeignKey = true, ThisKey = "DepartmentId"]
public Department Department 
{ 
    get { return department.Entity; }
    set { department.Entity = value; }
}
```

Now you can write queries similar to:

```
db.Employees.Where(x => x.Department.Name == "Accounting");
```

However, you *really* shouldn't be doing this by hand.